# How do I target the same instance when deploying using Serverless Components?

Tags: serverless, aws-serverless

My team and I are using Serverless Components (for NextJS - https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js) and it works great, except...

Every time one of us deploys, we seem to create a whole new instance on the AWS account.  Is there a way to target the same instance?  Or do I need to just manually set every ARN for every role, Lambda, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/issues/962#issuecomment-805185061

> You need to find a way to share your .serverless dir. If you only have one environment then you can add the directory to git. Otherwise search for "Multi-stage deployments" in the repo for some suggestions.